# Неправильная реализация задачи по выводу чисел из массива с использованием ArrayDeque

Tags: java

Имеется задача

Напишите программу, которая прочитает из System.in последовательность целых чисел, разделенных пробелами, затем удалит из них все числа, стоящие на четных позициях, и затем выведет получившуюся последовательность в обратном порядке в System.out.

Все числа влезают в int. Позиции чисел в последовательности нумеруются с нуля.

Все import объявлены за вас.
Пример ввода: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
Пример вывода: 10 8 6 4 2

Требования:

1. Необходимо наличие метода public static void main(String[] args)
2. Программа должна читать данные из консоли
3. Программа должна выводить текст в консоль

Я написал решение

```java
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        //ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream("1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10".getBytes());
        //System.setIn(bais); - для тестов в идее
        ArrayDeque<Integer> numbers = new ArrayDeque<>();
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] strArr = reader.nextLine().split(" ");
        int[] numArr = new int[strArr.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++) {
            numArr[i] = Integer.parseInt(strArr[i]);
            numbers.addFirst(numArr[i]);
        }
        for (int i = 0, max = numbers.size(); i < max; i++) {
            if ((i % 2) == 0) {
                numbers.pop();
            } else {
                System.out.print(numbers.pop() + " ");
            }
        }
    }
```

При этом получаю ошибку на платформе проверки -
"Ваш ответ не прошел тест!
Тест №2 провален, не верная реализация метода."
(Изначально не проходился тест №1, но я изменил код)

Вопрос 1 - как еще можно реализовать данную задачу с использованием ArrayDeque и дженериками в целом?
Вопрос 2 - Можно ли поправить данное решение? 
Согласен, теорию я понял фигово и что мне делать в данном случае - не представляю)

Проблема в том, что я использую дэкью как обычный массив. Но на самом ли деле это проблема или так и нужно?
А если я использую его неправильно, то как лучше сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы выводите массив в скобках и с запятыми `[10, 8, 6, 4, 2]`, а тестеру нужны только числа, разделённые пробелами. Так что обойдите `numbers` в цикле, выводя по одному элементу.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++) {
        numArr[i] = Integer.parseInt(strArr[i]);
        if ((i%2)!=0) numbers.addFirst(numArr[i]);
    }

    for (Integer t : numbers) {
               System.out.print(t + " ");
    }
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что использовать ArrayList нельзя. Платформа такое решение пропустит, но потом ментор попросит переделать с использованием Deque

Comment: ОК, это не проблема. Просто достаточно было бы более примитивной структуры данных.

Comment: Посмотрите, пожалуйста, новый код) Я попробовал сделать как нужно, но все-равно получаю примерно ту же ошибку

Comment: Нужно смотреть на чётность индекса, а не самих элементов, поэтому такой цикл for не пойдет, используйте классический

Comment: Я изменил цикл фор, но получил ровно тот же результат.

Comment: Вы, кажется, не проверяете, что  выводится. https://ideone.com/4vkWkM

Comment: В том-то и проблема, что даже моя изначальная версия программы корректно выводила необходимые числа, понимаете? Я просто не могу понять, как можно сделать по-другому.

Comment: Начальная версия правильно находила, но формат вывода был не тот, что нужно. То, что я в ideone написал  - проходит? Возможно, лишний пробел в конце мешает.

Comment: Блин, я и не заметил, что вы изменили код... И да, он проходит. Спасибо)
(Я минуту назад дописал ровно тот же фор)))